# How to access nanopi neo usb port

Tags: screen, nano

I have connected an Arduino to the USB port of the nanopi neo.the Arduino constantly sends serial data. On the nano pi neo, I have tried to use `screen`

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
```

but it doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong?

The nanopi neo runs Ubuntu core 4.x.x

Comment: Maybe different baud rate? Tried with `115200` ?

Comment: @fugitive sadly that did not work either.

Comment: Open a root shell, and retry :) I had similar issues with my arm devices, because `screen` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the exact answer, but I am able to use the Serial port 1 on the NanoPi Air. It is

```
screen /dev/ttyS1
```

For Serial port 2, that would be ttyS2.